# Limit on array size

Tags: c++, memory

I wrote the following code in c++ which was supposed to print as well as calculate all the prime numbers till n.
The code is perfectly working for n<=10000 but is not working for n>=100000.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,ans=0;
    cin>>n;
    vector <bool> v(n+1,true);
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        if(v[i]){
            cout<<i<<endl;
            ans++;
            for(int j=i*i;j<=n;j+=i)
                v[j]=false;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Kindly state the reason.
Thank you.

Comment: what happens for `n >= 100000` ?

Comment: Your "working" and "not working" range has an overlap. Does it work for *exactly* `10000` or not?

Comment: `j = i*i` will overflow at some point, but not at `100000`

Comment: details matter. Please clarify if `100000` is really the corner case, or just a guess

Comment: *"but is not working for n>=100000."* -- so for these `n`, your program starts spitting out the Fibonacci numbers instead of primes? Or maybe it draws ASCII art? Or implodes? Or... well, a lot of things fall under the description "not working". It might be wise to be more precise about what it does do, before imaginations run wild.

Comment: Why are you keeping the answer hostage?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your inner look, `j=i*i` will overflow a 32-bit signed integer at around 46341. The easiest fix there is to use a `long long` for `j` and also cast `i` correctly before multiplication.

So, change the inner loop to

```
for (auto j = static_cast<long long>(i) * i; j <= n; j += i)
```

And that should be it.

As a side note, please don't `#include` standard headers with double quotes; prefer `<vector>` and `<iostream>`.

**UPDATE**: As a more robust way of doing the same thing (and still using roughly the same code,) I'd suggest the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    size_t n, ans = 0; // A) Switch to size_t, which can accommodate the largest
                       //    size of a vector; if your number is larger, then we
                       //    can't make an array for it... 
    cin >> n;
    vector<bool> v (n, true); // B) Remove the chance of overflow; indices are
                              //    now shifted by one
    for(size_t i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (v[i - 1]) {
            cout << i << endl;
            ans++;
            if (n / i >= i) { // C) Check for possibility of overflow in `i*i`
                
                // D) Switch j to correct type
                // E) Check if `j+=i` overflowed
                for (size_t j = i * i; j <= n && j > i; j += i)
                    v[j - 1] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

The really important changes are A, C, and D. The other two, B and E are needed for complete correctness, but they only matter when you have enough actual memory in your system to *almost* overflow `size_t` (otherwise, the ctor for `vector` would throw.) This is completely probably on 32-bit systems, but impossible on 64-bit builds for now.

Also note that A, B, and D are "essentially" free (perf-wise,) but C and E do have some impact on running time (although probably tiny; E is the more onerous.)

Comment: Perhaps `unsigned long long` to increase the range just a little bit more. But ultimately there will still be a limit to what can be handled. And no cast needed if the type of `i` is the "correct"  to begin with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, note that I did not tell the OP to change the type of `i`, and there is a reason for that.

Comment: @yzt *"I did not tell the OP to change the type of i, and there is a reason for that."* -- Curious: what is the reason?

Comment: @JaMiT, I wanted to be only minimally intrusive, and fix the code without changing the specs. If they wanted an `int`, then nothing wrong with having an int for the input number. Another reason is that the we have a standard type that is twice as large as an `int` on some popular platforms (namely `long long`); no such luxury for `long long` itself. (That of course is not prohibitive, just much simpler this way. You can check for overflow in other ways. In fact, I'm going to amend my answer.)